# Button click event not firing from Controller - Beginner

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I have a View called `User.js` and i have a button in it.

```
...
buttons: [{
    text: 'Reset',
    id:'button'
}
...
```

Now i have my Controller named `User.js` , and i need to display a console.log message when the user clicks on the Button. The console message should be printed from the controller. My controller code is as follows;

```
Ext.define('Tangle.controller.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        console.log('works  ');
        this.control({
            'button': {
                click: this.refresbut
            }
        });
    },

    refreshbut: function() {
        console.log('button clicked ');
    }
});
```

According to this nothing hapense the console message is not printed. Can someone look into this please ??

CODE

```
Ext.define('Tangle.view.user.User' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel', 

    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        name: 'name'
    }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Submit',
        id:'button',
        name:'button'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Is your view renders alright? It would be beneficial if you include the view as a config for the controller. Also, you are hooking on all system buttons with your code (as controllers are system-global), are you aware of this?

Comment: My view renders well. I am new to EXJ JS 4, could you show me an example ? So i could understand it well

Comment: Have you had a look at the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/application_architecture)?

Comment: If you put console.log() in the first line of the controller's init, is it being called? Could you please submit the full code of your app?

Comment: Yes the first line is called.  I have added the code too

Comment: would help to see app.js

Comment: Another thing you can try is change the button id to `mybtn` and change your selector (within the control method) to `#mybtn`.

Comment: I already did that, it doesn't work too.

Comment: Well, i have had a problem in the app.js, i have not included the Controller name in it. Thanks for the tip. If you add that as an answer i would accept it. But one more thing, how could i pass values from the view to the Controller ?

Comment: I would suggest you open a new question for your last question. Do mention what exactly you wish to pass. Controllers can have `refs` to the view and can therefore access the view instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments. You have forgotten to include the controller in your app.